# How to get the index of the item from array using where method in dart?

Tags: dart

I have something like this,

```
List<Map<String, String>> ourUsersAndBuyers = [
  {"name":"Aman","seller":"ranjit"},
  {"name":"hari","seller":"sanjay"},
  {"name":"sima","seller":"saman"},
];
```

Now, I am finding the item in this array using where method like this,

```
var valueIs=ourUsersAndBuyers.where((element)=>element['name']=='sima' && element['seller']=='saman');
```

`valueIs` does give me the value, but now in this example as we can see where method has found the value in `2nd` index. How to get that index programmatically?
Or is there any other method, so that I can also find the particular item from array and also get the item index?
And for now, I am not looking answer using for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
var index = ourUsersAndBuyers.indexWhere((element) 
  => element['name'] == 'sima' && element['seller'] == 'saman');
```

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, but I am looking for something other than looping.